# Clerk auth not working after succesful login with google OAUTH

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, clerk

I implemented this login screen with React Native + Expo. After the user logs in successfully with the correct Google credentials, the app doesn't redirect the user to the SignedIn path. I logged all authentication data, but it's null.

LoginScreen.jsx

```
import { View, Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import Colors from "../../constants/Colors";
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
import { useWarmUpBrowser } from "../../../hooks/useWarmUpBrowser";
import { useOAuth } from "@clerk/clerk-expo";
import { useAuth } from "@clerk/clerk-expo";

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function LoginScreen() {
  useWarmUpBrowser();
  const { isLoaded, userId, sessionId, getToken } = useAuth();

  const { startOAuthFlow } = useOAuth({ strategy: "oauth_google" });
  const onPress = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const { createdSessionId, signIn, signUp, setActive } =
        await startOAuthFlow();
      console.log("done");
      console.log({ createdSessionId }); //""
      console.log({ isLoaded }); //true
      console.log({ userId }); //null
      console.log({ createdSessionId }, "session started"); //

      if (createdSessionId) {
        setActive({ session: createdSessionId });
      } else {
        // Use signIn or signUp for next steps such as MFA
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("OAuth error", err);
    }
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.section}>
      <Image
        style={styles.logoImage}
        source={require("../../../assets/images/login-screen.jpg")}
      />
      <Text style={styles.title}>Dein E Charging Finder App</Text>
      <Text style={styles.description}>
        Finde deine nächste Charger Station, plane deine Route and speichere
        deine Favoriten in der App
      </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onPress}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Google Login</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  section: {
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 25,
  },
  logoImage: {
    width: 400,
    height: 350,
    objectFit: "contain",
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  title: {
    fontFamily: "Poppins-ExtraBold",
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  description: {
    fontFamily: "Poppins-Regular",
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 5,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontFamily: "Poppins-SemiBold",
    color: Colors.secondary,
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});
```

App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import LoginScreen from "./app/screen/LoginScreen/LoginScreen";
import { ClerkProvider, SignedIn, SignedOut, useAuth } from "@clerk/clerk-expo";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const tokenCache = {
  async getToken(key: string) {
    try {
      return SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  },
  async saveToken(key: string, value: string) {
    try {
      return SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);
    } catch (err) {
      return;
    }
  },
};
export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    "Poppins-Regular": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Bold": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"),
    "Poppins-SemiBold": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf"),
    "Poppins-ExtraBold": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-ExtraBold.ttf"),
  });

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded]);

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }
  const SignOut = () => {
    const { isLoaded, signOut } = useAuth();
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Sign Out"
          onPress={() => {
            signOut();
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <ClerkProvider
      tokenCache={tokenCache}
      publishableKey={Constants.expoConfig.extra.clerkPublishableKey}
    >
      <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
        <SignedIn>
          <Text>You are Signed in</Text>
          <SignOut />
        </SignedIn>
        <SignedOut>
          <LoginScreen />
        </SignedOut>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
  },
});
```

I logged the auth, tried three older versions of the package